# Pass Dynamic Data to UIScrollView using Swift + Alamofire + Swifty-Json

Tags: json, swift, uiscrollview, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a **ViewController**, that has a **UIScrollView**. The UIScrollView loads three ViewControllers **vc0**, **vc1**, **vc2** :

[image]

## Problem

On ViewController, I load the data using Alamofire and SwiftyJson:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                     self.views = json["Views"].stringValue
                     print(self.views)
                    }
                    
            }
            case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
            }
            
    }
```

> Result from Print: **3603** which is correct.

I have tried:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.views = json["Views"].stringValue
    vc0.views = views
}
```

I have also tried adding **vc0.views = views** out of the alamofire call and put with the code that makes the views display in the UIScrollView:

```
    let vc0 = vc0(nibName: "vc0", bundle: nil)
    
    vc0.views = self.views
    
    self.addChildViewController(vc0)
    self.displayReportView.addSubview(vc0.view)
    vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    
    let vc1 = vc1(nibName: "vc1", bundle:nil)
    
    var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1.view.frame = frame1
    
    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.displayReportView.addSubview(vc1.view)
    vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    
    let vc2 = vc2(nibName: "vc2", bundle:nil)
    
    var frame2 = vc2.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    vc2.view.frame = frame2
    
    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.displayReportView.addSubview(vc2.view)
    vc2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    
    self.displayReportView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3, self.view.frame.size.height - 66);
```

> There are no errors in the console, it just does not display anything

## P.S

Everything else works, getting the data and showing the scroll views and sliding along them, the only thing that doesn't is passing the data from **ViewController** to either of the **vc0**, **vc1**, **vc2** views loaded in the **UIScrollView**.

## Question

How do I pass the data that is loaded on **ViewController** to the dynamically loaded views in the UIScrollView (**vc0**,**vc1**,**vc2**).

## Project Files

I have been following a tutorial to display the views etc.. Here are the tutorial files: https://www.veasoftware.com/s/Swipe-Navigation-Xcode-7.zip

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I'm not sure. I'm pretty noobie. Btw - I've been to your site before. Nice tutorials.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Have you deleted your comments? I was just gunna let u know there has been a solution.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu (Not that I sounded like a stalker there) - I just thought something went wrong or I had imagined talking to you.. It's been a long few hours, break needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the destination ViewController, either vc1 vc2 or vc3 how are you displaying the data?

If you have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   print(views)
}
```

try changing to the ViewDidAppear Method

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print(views)
}
```

Also, in your Alamofire Call, do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.views = json["Views"].stringValue
     self.vc0.views = self.views
}
```

I also suspect (by the way youve written your question) that your vc0,vc1,vc2 are declared after the alamofire so move

```
let vc0 = vc0(nibName: "vc0", bundle: nil)
```

to the top, just under your class declaration.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.